# Disabling warnings from lsp

Tags: lsp, clangd

I recently downloaded ncurses library...the clangd lsp is not picking up that library or its functions...but that's fine, I rarely use it

The issue is the lsp throws out errors each and every line because it can't find the declaration of ncurses functions

```
#include <ncursesw\ncurses.h>
int main(){
  char a;

  initscr();
  a=getch();
  printw("%c ",a); //initscr() getch() endwin() and printw()
  refresh();       //These functions throw lsp warning
                   //They all belong to ncurses library 
  getch();

  endwin();
}

Diagnostics:
1. Call to undeclared function "<somefunction>"; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Is there a way make the lsp ignore all implicit calls?
Or any other better way to solve this?

I use windows 11

Comment: It would help us to reproduce your problem if you could add a minimal example of `C` or `C++` program that lead to the error, the `compile_commands.json` that you use to tell clangd which flags to use. Interesting too is the OS that you are using (Windows, Linux, macOS).

Comment: Use the issue tracker of whatever LSP client you use.

Comment: I think you may be missing this step in setting up clangd: https://clangd.llvm.org/design/compile-commands#where-do-compile-commands-come-from